# In memory database that can be used during testing Nodejs Express App

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, package.json, in-memory-database

I want to use an in-memory database only while running unit test cases for express APIs.
For Instance in Java Spring we use H2 Database for testing and in main we used mysql.

So any recommendations on the same.

Also how I change the package.json so that while running `mocha` node will automatically catch that inmemory database for storing values.
Like in Spring we would application.properties in test folder and then spring would automatically fetch the test db settings.